# Expanding Persistent Volume Claim storage capactiy in GKE

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I increased the capacity of my elasticsearch persistent volume claim(PVC) but was unable to create the pod with that new volume.

I followed the following steps -

- Set the allowVolumeExpansion field to true in their StorageClass object(s)
- Scaled ElasticSearch Operator Deployment to 0 Replicas.
- Deleted the statefulset Object without deleting the pods using

  `kubectl delete sts <statefulset-name> --cascade=orphan`

Before deleting I saved the yaml of the statefulset using

```
kubectl get sts <statefulset-name> -o yaml
```

- Increased the storage in capacity in the yaml file of PVC.
- Recreated the StatefulSet with the new storage request by the yaml file I saved using

`kubectl apply -f file-name.yml`

- Scaled back the operator deployment to 1

But, when I recreated the stateful set,  the `CrashLoopBackOff` error is being shown every-time.

Following are some logs -

- readiness probe failed
- Likely root cause: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
- using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sdb)]], net usable_space [0b], net total_space [975.8mb], types [ext4]

What I can infer from these logs is that storage capacity of the PV has not increased. But the yaml of the same is showing changes.
Can anyone guide me here, what I am missing here ?

Comment: what do you see for your volume when you run: `kubectl get pv` and `kubectl get pvc -n NAMESPACE`?

Comment: @ericfossas, for both the commands, I am getting the same output. i.e.

`Capacity: 5Gi`
`Access Modes: RWO`
`Reclaim Policy: Delete`
`Status: Bound`
`StorageClass: Standard`
`Age: 126d`
`Claim: default/elasticsearch-data-hulk-es-default-0`

Comment: is 5Gi the original capacity or the updated one?

Comment: @ericfossas,  It is the updated one. Previously it was 1Gi

Comment: the steps you wrote are correct and it looks like the volume size did increase. my guess is that this is an issue with elasticsearch and not kubernetes.